Exchange 365 email signature doesn't work as expected
I'm a beginner in the area and I've been struggling for some time to make this email signature work, the problem is that depending on the screen, the texts don't fit properly where they should, but the real problem is that when the sender himself sends In an email, the signature appears normal as shown in the print below, but when it is sent to another person, the data is outside the image. Can anyone please help me?
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<div style="text-align: left; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <table style="width: 100%; font-family: 'DIN', sans-serif; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <!-- Imagem principal no topo -->
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/pRdSY8F/Background.jpg" alt="Background" style="display: block; width: 1000px; height: 350px; margin: 0 auto;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <!-- Conteúdo sobreposto à imagem -->
        <tr>
            <td style="position: relative; text-align: left; padding: 20px; color: #424242;">
                
                <!-- Nome e Título -->
                <div style="font-size: 28px; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; color: #424242; margin-top: -310px; margin-left: 460px;">
                    %%DisplayName%%
                </div>
                <div style="font-size: 23px; color: #439bdd; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 460px;">
                    %%Title%%
                </div>
                
                <!-- Número de telefone e website -->
                <div style="margin-top: 25px; color: #424242; margin-left: 455px;">
                    <a style="color: #424242; text-decoration: none; font-size: 20px;">%%MobileNumber%%</a>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 47px; color: #424242; margin-left: 455px; font-size: 18px;">
                    <a href="https://quimtia.com/pb/" style="color: #424242; text-decoration: none;">www.quimtia.com</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Endereço e Slogan -->
                <div style="font-size: 10px; margin-top: -225px; color: #424242; margin-left: -10px;">
                    Quimtia Brasil | Rua Maria Dalprá Berlesi, 229, Canguiri, Colombo - PR - Brasil | CEP: 83.412-055 | CNPJ 77.043.511/0001-15 | +55 41 2169-3100
                </div>
                <div style="font-size: 23px; margin-top: 190px; color: #424242; margin-left: 159px;">
                    Conexões de Valor.
                </div>
                
                <!-- Política de privacidade -->
                <div style="font-size: 8px; margin-top: 99px; color: #424242; margin-left: -10px;">
                    Clique <a href="https://quimtia.com/wp-content/themes/quimtia/pdf/aviso_advertencia_por.pdf" style="color: #424242; text-decoration: none;"><b>aqui</b></a> para ver a nossa política de privacidade. 
                    Clic <a href="https://quimtia.com/wp-content/themes/quimtia/pdf/aviso_advertencia_esp.pdf" style="color: #424242; text-decoration: none;"><b>aquí</b></a> para ver nuestra política de privacidade. 
                    Clic <a href="https://quimtia.com/wp-content/themes/quimtia/pdf/aviso_advertencia_ing.pdf" style="color: #424242; text-decoration: none;"><b>here</b></a> to learn about our privacy policy.
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

PRINT1
PRINT2
I believe it's some incompatibility with tags I used in CSS but I've tried everything and I can't get it to work
